# Most efficient way to translate words in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, internationalization

Hi I wanted to ask if this what you see below is quickest and most efficient way to translate words in python. I only need translation to english from other foreign languages. Would it be more efficient to divide dictionary into one dictionary for every language or is it good the way it is right now? It would be nice if code would work in python 2.7 and 3.x and above. In code below I have to change iteritems to items which is no big deal.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

dct = {'apple': ['apfel', 'pomme', 'manzana', 'jabłko'],
       'pineapple': ['ananas', 'ananas', 'piña', 'ananas']}


def translate(q):
    for eng_word, trans_list in dct.iteritems():
        for trans_word in trans_list:
            if trans_word == q:
                q = eng_word
                print q
                return q

query = 'pomme'

query = translate(query)

query = 'ananas'

query = translate(query)

print query
```

Comment: If you only need to translate *into* English you should go the other way so you can do it in constant time (that is, use the foreign words as keys in the dictionary).  But what happens if the "same" word has two meanings depending on the language?

Comment: It just translates first match. It should be the quickest way right? I'm quite confident that in my program there won't be same words (it'll have quite limited vocabulary for program purposes only)

Comment: OK.  Well, to answer your question, no, this is far from the most efficient way because you potentially have to scan the entire list every time.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I'm new to programming so I'm probably wrong but won't it stop scanning trough list after first 'return' match?

Comment: Yes.  But the worst-case performance is linear since if the word you want is the last element of the last array you need to scan everything.  On the other hand, if you key your dictionary by the translation the worst-case performance is constant regardless of which word you want.

Comment: See the Python time complexity page as well:  https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: Got it. Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a dictionary whose keys are foreign words and whose values are English words. Then you can translate in O(1) time with one line of code.

```
d = {'apfel': 'apple', 'jablko': 'apple', 'ananas': 'pineapple', 'manzana': 'apple', 'pomme': 'apple', 'pina': 'pineapple'}
print d["pomme"]
```

Comment: Surely you have to account for the case where I put in a word that you don't know about.

Comment: Ok, then you can do `print d.get("pomme", "<No translation available>")`

Comment: Thanks for quick answer